# jquery mobile swipe page for settings similar to Facebook

Tags: jquery, html, facebook, jquery-mobile, touch

I am beginning to learn jQuery Mobile. I was wondering on mobile when you swipe with your finger to the left, you can show a settings page half on the screen, similar to Facebook.

Link to screenshot [here](http://themeforest.net/theme_previews/3018322-tiger-jquery-mobile-web-template-web-app?index=4)

How could I do that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This can be useful:

JQuery-Mobile-Slide-Menu: https://github.com/tegansnyder/JQuery-Mobile-Slide-Menu
A sliding menu similar to Facebook and Path's approach to menu design on mobile. This is a JQuery Mobile example. DEMO URL below:

http://www.tegdesign.com/tegansnyder-JQuery-Mobile-Slide-Menu

Comment: is it possible to add one doing the same thing to the other side, so there is one left and right? Again similar to Facebook? cheers